# force r not to round results after mutate

Tags: r

I have a set of variables starting with `ppp_` that corresponding to the `id` column of the data frame. I want to divide each of the col from `X1` to `X5` by the corresponding variable `ppp_xxx`.

```
ppp_TZA = 803.8115234375
ppp_ZMB = 0.539304196834564
ppp_SGP = 0.879599809646606
ppp_TUR = 1.162452

> set.seed(10000)
> dd <- data.frame(id=c("TZA", "ZMB", "SGP", "TUR"), matrix(runif(5*4)*1000, nrow=4))
> dd
   id        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5
1 TZA 321.68642 452.6506 106.8596 859.7612 428.8721
2 ZMB  94.38782 386.7600 837.7849 728.1341 243.5673
3 SGP 468.95386 550.1910 488.5095 921.8389 611.7136
4 TUR 990.72595 838.9120 494.1026 580.5896 262.3972
> dd %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(.cols=(2:4), .fns = ~.x/get(paste0("ppp_",id))))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  id         X1      X2       X3    X4    X5
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 TZA     0.400   0.563    0.133  860.  429.
2 ZMB   175.    717.    1553.     728.  244.
3 SGP   533.    626.     555.     922.  612.
4 TUR   852.    722.     425.     581.  262.
```

However, the result is rounding out the digits automatically without me set rounding. I tried `options(digits=10)` but it doesn't help.

Comment: The result is not rounded, only displaying 3 significant digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display more digits by changing the options for the tibble, i.e. `options(pillar.sigfig) = 7`. It's worth noting that the digits are not actually lost, just not displayed in the frame, i.e. if you did:

```
x <- dd %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(.cols=(2:4), .fns = ~.x/get(paste0("ppp_",id))))
x[1, 2] %>% as.numeric()
```

you would see the full values and confirm they are there.