# bind_rows() rounded data when they have different precisions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)    
las1 <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
names(las1) <- c("t1", 't2', "t3")

las2 <- c(0.4997, 0.4995, 0.4982)
names(las2) <- c("t1", 't2', "t3")

> las1
 t1  t2  t3 
0.5 0.5 0.5 

> las2
    t1     t2     t3 
0.4997 0.4995 0.4982 

las3 <- bind_rows(las1, las2)

> las3
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     t1    t2    t3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.5   0.5   0.5  
2 0.500 0.500 0.498
```

You can see here that `bind_rows()`automatically rounded the input data, how can I adjust precision or can I turn this feature off?

Comment: Run `options(pillar.sigfig = 7)` in the console and try again.

Comment: I had a similar question, basically they are not rounded, just displayed differently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66945453/force-r-not-to-round-results-after-mutate